# Python HTML email variable not correct (Ã,À,Ç,etc)?

Tags: html, python-3.x, email, outlook

So, I'm typing an app in Python to read out of an excel file the name and email. When I pass along the "name" of the recipient, things like "Índia" or "Indíra" or "Ação" look really weird.

Which is strange because the rest of the email is correctly formatted, and accents / ç's etc don't look weird. Only the "name" variables.

Here's my code:

```
template = """
<p>{},</p>

<img src="cid:image-img" width=100%>

<p>Com os melhores cumprimentos,</p>
<p>A equipa</p>
"""

with open('Book1.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    distro = [row for row in reader]


chunks = [distro[x:x+30] for x in range(0, len(distro), 30)]
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application') #to dispatch outlook
for chunk in chunks:
    for name, email in chunk:
        message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        message.To = email
        message.Subject = "Save the date!"
        message.HTMLBody = template.format(name)
        image = message.Attachments.Add(imagem_absolute) 
        image.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "image-img")

        message.Save()
```

Comment: What’s the encoding of `Book1.csv`?

Comment: Outlook doesn't change encodings. Check your workbook's data instead.